# Prevent multiple python scripts from accessing a single file simultaneously

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, fcntl

I am trying to create a series of images (where each is a composite of 12 smaller images). The blank composite images and the smaller component images already exist. I've written a python script which appends the (small) image at a certain position to each (large) image in the composite series. I would like to be able to run multiple instances of this script for each of the 12 positions simultaneously. However, when two instances attempt to write to the same composite image, one or both of the component images will fail to append to the composite.

**How do I prevent other instances of my script from accessing a file that is currently being accessed?**

I  have tried file-locking, but haven't been able to get it to work (example below)

```
import sys
from PIL import Image
import fcntl

small = str(sys.argv[1])      # component image (small)
composite = str(sys.argv[2])  # composite image (large)
x_coord = int(sys.argv[3])    # x-coordinate of small image
y_coord = int(sys.argv[4])    # y-coordinate of small image

img = Image.open(small)
fo = open(composite, 'ab')

while True:
    try:
        # Lock the file if not already in use
        fcntl.flock(fo, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
        break
    except:
        # If file is locked, wait for it to be unlocked
        print("Drat! It's locked!")
        time.sleep(5.)

comp_img = Image.open(fo)
img = img.resize((500,500))
comp_img.paste(img,(x_coord,y_coord))
comp_img.save(composite)

# Unlock the file for other instances to use
fcntl.flock(fo, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
```

I know my use of `sleep` in the try-except block (and likely a great many other things) is sub-optimal but I'll worry about this when I can get it to work

Comment: I'd argue this is a lot simpler if you make your script's *caller* responsible for only running one process at a time on a composite file, rather than your script having to detect if it is safer to write to it or not.

Comment: I just made a little stripped dsown version of your code appending to a text file and it worked as expected (Unbntu 18 based system). You said "I have tried file-locking, but haven't been able to get it to work" - what happens when you run the code you gave (particularly several of them in parallel)?

Comment: Also, do you immediately close the file after you release the lock? Just a guess but I wonder if there's some race condition between the process releasing the lock but the image file contents not yet being flushed to disk. I wonder if you could call flush (and/or close) on the comp file before you release the lock on it.

Comment: IMHO, this isn't a very sensible approach. You will end up having to re-read and re-write the large image as many times as you have parallel processes. Firstly that is unlikely to be any faster, secondly you will get image degradation if you use lossy JPEG, and you will pay the penalty of slow PNG many times over if you use that in order to be lossless. Take a step back, and say what you are really trying to do and you should get better assistance - there are some clever folk in Stack Overflow.